# Removing uppercase/lowercase dupes in list

Tags: linux, bash, macos, grep, wc

I put together a small script that is supposed to search through files of a certain type in a directory accumulating unique word counts > 4 characters, but it's not working as expected.

1. It doesn't eliminate the same word regardless of case.
2. I'm not sure how to tally up the totals of each word obviously.
3. Lastly, is this an efficient way to do this (if it actually worked?).

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

file_list=()
while IFS= read file ; do
    file_list=("${file_list[@]}" "$file")
    tr -sc 'A-Za-z' '\012' < "$file" | sort | uniq -c | egrep "\w{4,}" >> words.txt
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.c")

# echo "${file_list[@]}"

cat words.txt | sort -u | sort -nr 
echo "" > words.txt
```

example output:

```
  38 char
  35 return
  25 static
  18 year
  18 char
  10 COLS
  10 CHAR
```

How would I remove the duped word `char` in the example above, but getting it's count in all files?

Comment: How is "word" defined? Is it a string separated by a space/tab/new-line or something more ?

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein: a-zA-Z (four chars +), separated by spaces, newline, tab, i think covers it... that's what I'm going for at least. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, convert to all-lowercase as the first step in your pipeline.

```
tr A-Z a-z <"$file" | tr -sc a-z '\012' | ...
```

Second, do the sorting and counting at the end of the whole thing instead of inside the loop:

```
...
  tr A-Z a-z <"$file" | tr -sc a-z '\012' 
done < <(find ...) | sort | uniq -c | egrep "\w{4,}" >words.txt
```

Comment: The second part doesn't? It should have the desired result of showing the totals across all files.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to make the find part work like yours, so that's whats missing. I used the first part of your answer though with the rest of my code like this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a2c44d1fd67f70bf84ccb36fb5c3d651

Comment: The find shouldn't change.  The part between parentheses should be exactly the same as your original code.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is:

```
awk -v RS='\\s' 'length()>3{cnt[tolower($0)]++} END{for (word in cnt) print cnt[word], word}' *.c
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS and `\s`, it's a simple tweak with other awks:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (length($i)>3) cnt[tolower($i)]++} END{for (word in cnt) print cnt[word], word}' *.c
```

wrt your question asking is your current approach efficient - no, it's very inefficient and will run at least an order of magnitude slower than the script I posted above. Read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

If you need to do this on all files found recursively then, this might be all you need:

```
awk -v RS='\\s' 'length()>3{cnt[tolower($0)]++} END{for (word in cnt) print cnt[word], word}' $(find -type f -name '*.c' -print)
```

otherwise this will do it:

```
find -type f -name '*.c' -print0 |
xargs -0 cat |
awk -v RS='\\s' 'length()>3{cnt[tolower($0)]++} END{for (word in cnt) print cnt[word], word}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following uses [Associative Arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays#Associative_Arrays) ( Bash 4 ) to store the word as the key, and its occurrences as the value:

```
declare -A arr
while read -r word; do
    arr[$word]=$(( ${arr[$word]} + 1 ))
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.c' -exec grep -E '\w{4,}' {} \; | tr -s '[:space:]' \\n)
```

Yes, it can perform faster, but notice: If you'll change `find`'s `\;` command termination to `+`, `grep` will yield also the file name as a part of the output ( which is the key, in our case ). We do not want this kind of behavior. Thus, if you have GNU `grep` - add the `-h` option alongside `find`'s `+` command termination.

Quoted from `man grep`:

> ```
>   -h, --no-filename
>           Suppress the prefixing of file names on output.  This is the default when there is only one file (or only standard input) to search.
> ```

i.e. :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.c' -exec grep -hE '\w{4,}' {} + | tr -s '[:space:]' \\n
```

---

For testing, I created the following content:

```
$ cat 1.c 2.c 
char return
char    char    int
char
char    switch      return
int
CHAR switch
COLS
year
static
char
CHAR
INT
int
main
return case
long
double
```

I created a script named ***sof***, which contains the relevant code above plus a `declare -p arr` to validate the associative array contents after execution:

```
$ ./sof
declare -A arr='([return]="3" [static]="1" [switch]="2" [int]="1" [CHAR]="2" [char]="6" [COLS]="1" [double]="1" [main]="1" [case]="1" [long]="1" [year]="1" )'
```

It looks good, so now we can simply print it according to your requested output:

```
$ for k in "${!arr[@]}";do v="${arr[$k]}"; printf '%s %s\n' "$v" "$k";done
1 static
3 return
2 switch
1 int
6 char
2 CHAR
1 COLS
1 main
1 double
1 case
1 long
1 year
```

Comment: One thing thing that might not work is the bash version being too specific; I'm hoping this will work on versions 3.2+ - thanks

Comment: @NedSchneebly It requires Bash 4+. But might be useful for someone in the future.